# Implementation no longer in use, but files are still present

Tags: android-studio, maven, github, gradle, intellij-idea

I feel dumb for asking this, but I thought that GitHub and Gradle would fully manage dependencies in Android Studio.

I commented an implementation from Maven (by using "//") and then invalidated caches and restarted, then clean project and rebuild.

```
//    implementation "com.some-implementation:the-implementation:1.0.0"
```

And to my surprise when I [double shift](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/05/when-the-shift-hits-the-fan-search-everywhere/) for searching project files in IntelliJ the file is still there and accesible.

I've been working on a personal project for some time now, and after finding out that files of unused dependencies are still present on the project, now I wonder how on earth will I get rid of them entirely.

I cannot even remember how many implementations have been used and then abandoned.

Do these files end up adding to the compile time, or to the size of the build?

Comment: I cannot follow you. Could you be more specific and give an example?

Comment: I added information but, I believe I forgot a very important tag, this is in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure , but i think that even with `gradle clean build` wont delete the old files , If you can locate the android cache , usually at `Users/%USER_NAME%/.android/cache-build` , you can safely delete all the unwanted jars.

But with my naïf understanding that even deleting gradle cache and the android cache you will keep seeing those files in the Search everywhere . and its probably related to the search mechanism .

But i have no idea why this will be an issue for you , its cached and am almost sure that it wont be loaded to any cloned or newley used project .

So opening new project or clone your current progress to a new location will remove these unwanted dependencies .